# AngularJs asynchronous data binding

Tags: angularjs

I'm very new to AngularJs and I have simple question. I want to put the name. But this name has one value at first but after 0.3-0.5 sec it have other value. I don't know how to bind it, that the value could change.

HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="FormController">
    <h2 >
        {{getName()}}<br>
        <span class="icon-f-gear"></span>
        <small>Procesas</small>
    </h2>
</div>
```

Angular controller:

```
var App = angular.module('form', ['ui.bootstrap']);

App.controller('FormController', ['$scope' ,'$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.tasks = [];
    $scope.socket.stomp.subscribe("/app/tasks", function (message) {
        if ($scope.tasks.length !=0){
            $scope.tasks.removeAll();
        }
        JSON.parse(message.body).forEach(function (el) {
            $scope.tasks.push(el);
        });
    });
    $scope.getName = function(){
        return $scope.tasks[0].form.name;
    };
```

I'm using Stomp protocol, it gives me data not instantly, because it has to send request to server and get it back, it takes time. I tried to debug after the request variable $scope.tasks[0].form.name changes from undefined to "Institution", but in the screen undefined stays, how to bind variable to change the value dinamically. Thanks for help in advance!

**UPDATE**
Problem solved, I just had to use $scope.apply(...) function. Code here:

```
var App = angular.module('form', ['ui.bootstrap']);

App.controller('FormController', ['$scope' ,'$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.tasks = [];
    $scope.socket.stomp.subscribe("/app/tasks", function (message) {
        if ($scope.tasks.length !=0){
            $scope.tasks.removeAll();
        }
        JSON.parse(message.body).forEach(function (el) {
            $scope.tasks.push(el);
        });
        $scope.apply(function(){$scope.tasks});
    });
    $scope.getName = function(){
        return $scope.tasks[0].form.name;
    };
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably the subscribe callback is not being called in angular context. Try to wrap the callback code in `$scope.$apply` and see if it works

```
 $scope.socket.stomp.subscribe("/app/tasks", function (message) {
     $scope.$apply(function() {
        if ($scope.tasks.length !=0){
            $scope.tasks.removeAll();
        }
        JSON.parse(message.body).forEach(function (el) {
            $scope.tasks.push(el);
        });
     });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I used this $scope.apply(...) function and everything works just fine. Although I used it just on the variable: $scope.$apply(function() {$scope.tasks};

Answer (score 0):

I believe the method you are calling returns undefined, because it has no data.
In other words: give it an initial value, and it should work

I would rewrite it to:

```
<div ng-controller="FormController">
    <h2>
        {{formName}}<br>
        <span class="icon-f-gear"></span>
        <small>Procesas</small>
    </h2>
</div>
```

And

```
App.controller('FormController', ['$scope' ,'$http', function($scope, $http) { 

$scope.formName = '';
--- rest of code
```

Or, if you wish to keep it in the current way:
    App.controller('FormController', ['$scope' ,'$http', function($scope, $http) {

```
$scope.tasks = [];
$scope.tasks[0].form.name = '';
```

or

```
$scope.getName = function(){
    return ($scope.tasks.length > 0) ? $scope.tasks[0].form.name : '';
};
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your time, but i tried this earlier too, it didn't change model, earlier answer suggestion to use $scope.apply(...) worked as a charm.